# Как исправить ошибку "No matching constructor for initialization"?

Tags: c++, qt

Когда я пытаюсь объявить image вот так:

```
if (item->image().save(&buffer, "PNG"))
    {
        MyImage image;
        image.setData(imageData);
    }
```

выдает вот такую ошибку : No matching constructor for initialization "MyImage"

myimage.h

```
#ifndef MYIMAGE_H
#define MYIMAGE_H

#include <QByteArray>
#include <QString>

class MyImage
{
public:
    MyImage(const QByteArray &data,const QString &id = "");
    void setData(const QByteArray &data);
    void setId(const QString &id);
    QByteArray data() const;
    QString id() const;
private:
    QByteArray mData;
    QString mId;

};

#endif // MYIMAGE_H
```

Comment: Код в вопросе следует привести к виду [mcve]

Comment: В строчке `MyImage image;` должен вызываться отсутствующий у Вас конструктор без аргументов, т.е. конструтор вида `MyImage();` в классе `MyImage`

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка исправилась, когда добавил байтовый массив:

```
 MyImage(const QString &id = "", const QByteArray &data = QByteArray());
```